# Google custom search: Query limit, create links to search result page?

Tags: google-api, search-engine

I am planning to create a custom search for my website and just want to consider below points

1. Is there any query limit/day with Google Custom Search?
2. **Can we create direct link to search result page of Custom Search**, like

http://xyz.com/result.htm?cx=partner-pub-0567817491096263%3Acozw148egu5&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4+&sa=Search&lid=HI&siteurl=localhost%3A88%2Findex.htm%3Flid%3Dhi

**Is it legal** or breaking any Terms of Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CS limit is 100 queries/day (afterwards it will cost you).

You should be aware that the custom search is limit to 100 results.

AFASIK - there is no legal limitation of creating direct links. After all you pay per query.

Comment: I am not agree to 100 queries/day limit, as I am making many queries and Google is not blocking extra queries.

Comment: @Vipul I said that the limit is 100 results per querry, Google won't block extra queries - they simply charge for them ( 5$/1000q)  see https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Thanks TheSimon, please also advise me for 2nd query. Somebody told me that its not the correct way to provide direct links to result page.